# ¿Como mostrar la descripción de una tabla de valores multiples en PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

Tengo creada una tabla llamada estaciones

```
id_estacion estacion 
1 Radio la Que buena
2 Radio Corazón
3 Radio la Chévere
```

Esos  valores los despliego en un select list(selección múltiple) con un display estación y return id_estacion esos datos se almacenas en la tabla form_request

¿Cómo hacer un select de la tabla form_request y que me muestren separados por coma los valores por nombre de estación y no por id_estacion ?

Hasta ahora tengo este código que solo funciona con valores single

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN ESTACION = '1' THEN (SELECT ESTACION FROM estacion WHERE id_eiexport = '1')
WHEN ESTACION = '2' THEN (SELECT ESTACION FROM estacion WHERE id_eiexport = '2')
WHEN ESTACION = '3' THEN (SELECT ESTACION FROM estacion WHEREid_eiexport = '3')
FROM FORM_REQUEST
```

Quiero que mi select muestre(separados por coma) cuando la persona hizo selección múltiple

```
Radio Corazón, Radio la Chévere
Radio La Que buena, Radio Corazón
```

Pero me retorna por id_estacion esto:

```
id | estacion
_____________
1  | 2, 3
2  | 1, 2
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo q tienes hecho hasta ahora, y pon un ejemplo claro de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Me devuelvo un valor nulo cuando esta almacenado en la tabla FORM_REQUEST dos estaciones o mas al hacer el select case

Comment: Henriquez podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y responder mi inquietud pero no me ha sido util.

Comment: Pq no te sirvio dime q paso para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Por ejemplo una persona seleccionara multiselect(no single) estaciones que podrían ser Radio Corazón y Radio Chévere  entonces al guardar en mi tabla me retorna los id de dichas estaciones y quiero que se guarde la leyenda Radio Corazón, Radio Chévere (separados por coma).  Dependiendo de que seleccione una persona, no la lista entera ya que es una elección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero a alguien le sirva si usa Oracle Apex, simplemente enlace la lista de selección multiple a un query como este:

```
 select estacion a, estacion b 
 from estacion
```

Ya con eso se guardara en la tabla **Radio Chereve,Radio Corazón**  y no con el id_estacion **3,2**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la **función listagg**:

```
select listagg(estacion, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY estacion) Estaciones
from form_request
group by id
```

La **función de agregación listagg** retorna una cadena y es utilizada para transformar datos de múltiples filas en una lista de valores concatenados y separados  por un delimitador específico que en este caso es la coma(**','**). Por último se utiliza la **cláusula group by** para obtener todas las estaciones que tienen en común el mismo id.

**Referencias:**

http://mundodb.es/funcion-oracle-listagg

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php